# How do I add Keynote templates/themes to the iPad Keynote application

Tags: ipad, iwork-keynote

I work for a major blue-chip company that insists we do presentations in the company style.

They make keynote templates available, but I don't know how to install them on the ipad.

I note that some third parties now sell keynote templates for the iPad that can be downloaded and installed.

How can I convert and upload my company templates into the iPad keynote application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one approach. It's not ideal but gets the job done.

http://www.themobilepresenter.com/article.php/keynote-ipad-theme